# build the .dylib from Rcpp 0.11.1

Tags: c++, r, shared-libraries, rcpp

I recenlty switch to R version 3.1.0 which force me (hopefully) to install Rcpp version 0.11.1 that I use intensively in my c++ application. However, when installing Rcpp 0.11.1 I realised that it does not build automatically the .dylib library file that I need in my c++ program (contrary to the previous version Rcpp_0.10.4 that I used) but only the .so file. How can I build this libRcpp.dylib file that I really need to run my c++ code? Thanks in advance for your expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the release announcements for Rcpp 0.11.0 -- there is second explicit library anymore.   See the rcpp-devel mailing list or previous posts here.

Comment: Does it mean that I need to redesign my c++ project architecture or is there any way to proceed to tackle the lack of .dylib file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since Rcpp 0.11.0 you no longer need one. That is clearly documented.

Comment: And there are now 201 packages on CRAN that use Rcpp. That is 201 worked examples of how to use it. Pick one, or two, or three, ... and see how they do it.  Really not that hard.